# How to link NDB with Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm developing a storage system, and I'm using NDB Python Datastore.
I need to link it with the Database created in Google App Engine to store all the info I get there.

How can I achieve that?

In addition, I have not already create the database in Google App Engine, is it better to do in a terminal or using the Google Developers Console?

Comment: your question does not seem to make much sense. The database created in GAE is the datastore. If you want to create a SQL database you have to do that explicitly. And then to "link" them you just write code that does that.

Comment: No, I don't want a SQL database. My problem is that I don't know if is necessary some code to use NDB to handle the datastore. In case no, I suppose creating the database I will have access to it, don't I?

Comment: NDB handles the datastore directly, you just create models and push entities to it

Comment: have you done the tutorials? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingdatastore

Comment: Yes of course. Reading your opinions, I realise my fault has been not to create the database before handling it. I will prove to create it and I told you if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you are confusing the local development Datastore with the production datastore? Everything you create in the development environment stays there and is not "deployed" with the code.

Comment: Oh, I solved the problem, so all it's ok. Thanks all!